# Nant Build Error-- Nested build failed

Tags: nant

I have a HelloNAnt.build file inside the directory:

```
D:\third party components\nant\WhatThis
```

My nant exe is placed at

```
C:\Program Files\nant
```

So I cd to `D:\third party components\nant\WhatThis`, type in the following command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\nant\bin\nant.exe" HelloNAnt.build
```

I got a build failed error, saying target `HelloNAnt.build` does not exist in this project.

What actually went wrong?

The content of `HelloNAnt.build`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Hello World" default="hello">
    <target name="hello">
        <echo>Hello</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You omitted the `-buildfile` option, which specifies the path to the buildfile that you want NAnt to run:

```
"C:\Program Files\nant\bin\nant.exe" -buildfile:HelloNAnt.build
```

However, in your case, you needn't provide any options at all.  NAnt will search the current directory for a file with a `.build` extension and run it.